# system.StackOverflowException: "Выдано исключение типа "System.StackOverflowException"." c#

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня есть Form1 в которой я создаю Form2

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
```

, затем в Form2 я создаю Form3

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Form3 form3 = new Form3();
```

и в форме Form3 мне нужно обратиться к объекту на Form1.
Если я в Form3 создам Form1 то уйду в рекурсию.
Как обратиться из Form3 к Form1 не создавая Form1, а обратиться к уже существующей?

Comment: в Конструктор Форм2 передать объект Форм1. В конструктор Форм 3 передать объект Форм1

Comment: @ArchDemon как я могу это сделать? подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: @zakrieff вам уже дан ответ на момент написания этого комментария, зачем спамите?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new Form1` не позволит вам ни к чему обратиться, а создаст новую копию формы и будет у вас 2 Form1, в свою очередь 1 форма создаст 2, 2 создаст 3, 3 создаст 1, 1 форма создаст 2, 2 создаст 3, 3 создаст 1, 1 форма создаст 2, 2 создаст 3, 3 создаст 1, 1 форма создаст 2, 2 создаст 3, 3 создаст 1, 1 форма создаст 2, 2 создаст 3, 3 создаст 1, 1 форма создаст 2, 2 создаст 3, 3 создаст 1, 1 форма создаст 2, 2 создаст 3, 3 создаст 1, 1 форма создаст 2, 2 создаст 3, 3 создаст 1, 1 форма создаст 2, 2 создаст 3, 3 создаст 1, `StackOverflowException`

Для главной формы можно например так

```
private Form1 mainForm;

private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mainForm = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().First();
}
```

Чтобы создать обоаботчик `Load`, надо в дизайнере ткнуть по пустому месту на форме двойным кликом.

Comment: именно это я и описал в проблеме. Но мне нужно из Form3 обратиться к объекту на Form1, не создавая Form1, как я могу это сделать? я новичок

Comment: @zakrieff Уже написал в ответе, обновите

Comment: "Application" не содержит определение для "MainForm". Извиняюсь за глупые вопросы...

Comment: @zakrieff поправил код

Comment: отладчик выдал System.InvalidOperationException: "Последовательность не содержит элементов"

Comment: @zakrieff а, логично, формы же еще не успели создаться. Нужно сделать следующее. В поле просто напишите `private Form1 form;`. В дизайнере надмите двойным кликом по пусому месту на форме, появится обработчик события `Form3_Load`, в нем напишите `form = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().First();`. Обновил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, это работает!! Подскажите пожалуйста, это единственный способ обращения к форме? Вы часто пользуетесь таким способом?

Comment: @zakrieff нет, не единственный. Можете при создании дочерней формы передать ей ссылку на родительскую через конструктор. Примеров полинтернета. В конструкторе `private Form1 parentForm; public Form2(Form1 parent) { InitializeComponent(); parentForm = parent; }` а вызывать вот так `new Form2(this)`.

Comment: @zakrieff можно передать ссылку на родителя через `.ShowDialog(this)`, можно использовать статическое публичное свойство и еще куча способов. Например самый сложный для понимания, но самый простой в использовании - IoC контейнер (внедрение зависимостей), но это уже примерно высший пилотаж.

Comment: Это  интересно. Но мне пока сложно понять, с какими сложностями можно столкнуться в том или ином способе. Спасибо большое за ответы.

Comment: @zakrieff эта сложность далеко не самая сложная из того что еще предстоит

Comment: Не могли бы вы, пожалуйста, посоветовать какую-нибудь литературу по c# winforms, разработка БД, думаю, читающим этот комментарий , будет полезен ваш ответ!